# WordPress Custom Post Type Category Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called tutorials.

I can go to mysite.com/tutorials and get a list of all the tutorials.

I have also created a custom taxonomy called tutorial_categories with the following code:

```
register_taxonomy(
        'tutorial_categories',
        'tutorials',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Tutorial Categories',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Tutorial Category',
                'new_item_name' => "New Tutorial Category"
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'hasArchive' => true
        )
    );
```

I think this is part of a plugin to allow me to do this.

How can I create a category page for a tutorial_category, so if someone goes to:

mysite.com/tutorials/php/

They will get a list of tutorials (custom post type) with the custom taxonomy of PHP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have done some Googling and I cannot seem to find the answer to this question.

Thank you!

Leon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make a new page template.

The easiest way is to copy your current page.php file and save it as: tutorials-page.php.

At the top include this:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Tutorials Page
*/
?>
```

Then replace the loop in the new tutorials-page.php file with the following custom loop:

```
<?php $args=array( 
'post_type' => 'tutorials', //set the post_type to use.
'taxonomy' => 'tutorial_categories', // set the taxonomy to use.
'term' => 'php', //set which term to use. 
'posts_per_page' => 10  // how many posts or comment out for all.       
);

$tutorialsloop = new WP_Query($args);
if($tutorialsloop->have_posts()) : while($tutorialsloop->have_posts()) :
$tutorialsloop->the_post();

get_template_part( 'content' ); //or whatever method your theme uses for displaying content. 

endwhile; endif; //end the custom post_type loop

?>
```

Then make a new page and assign this new page template to it.

Comment: I don't understand how this is the correct answer. This will not generate a permalink for `/custom_post_type/taxonomy`. Also it's a very hardcoded solution, not really scalable..

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this but looks promising.

http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-archives/

Comment: Thank you. So by looking at that article and the code I posted above. I should be able to create a taxonomy page: taxonomy-tutorial_categories.php and then go to mysite.com/tutorials/php-tutorials ("php-tutorials" is the slug for the PHP category under my custom post type tutorials). This still doesn't work, I just get page not found :( Thanks for your help!